# How to get Twitter UserName By email and Password Using httpwebrequest C#?

Tags: c#

This is my code
I made this via three steps:

1. I Login to twitter and get the authenticity_Token then
2. I login to twitter by using email and password.
3. the last step, I want to go to the input and get the userName
   But I am not get the username

   ```
   string authenticity_token = string.Empty;
   // get auth token
   {
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://twitter.com/login");
       //request.Proxy = null;
       request.Proxy = WebProxy;
       request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
       request.ReadWriteTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
       request.KeepAlive = false;
       request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // was true
       request.CookieContainer = cc;
       request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       string SourceCode = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

       authenticity_token = Regex.Match(SourceCode, "name=\"authenticity_token\" value=\".*?\"").Value.Replace("name=\"authenticity_token\" value=", "").Replace("\"", "");
   }
   // login
   {
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://twitter.com/sessions");
       //request.Proxy = null;
       request.Proxy = WebProxy;
       request.Timeout = 10000;
       request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
       request.KeepAlive = false;
       request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // was true
       request.CookieContainer = cc;
       request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
       request.Method = "POST";
       string log= "/";
       string post_data = string.Format("session%5Busername_or_email%5D={0}&session%5Bpassword%5D={1}&authenticity_token={2}&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login={3}&remember_me=1", email, password, authenticity_token, log);
       byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_data);
       request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
       request.ContentLength = array.Length;
       Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
       dataStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
       dataStream.Close();
       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   }

   // go to account settings and extract the username from the input box
   {
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://twitter.com/settings/account");
       //request.Proxy = null;
       request.Proxy = WebProxy;
       request.Timeout = 10000;
       request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
       request.KeepAlive = false;
       request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // was true
       request.CookieContainer = cc;
       //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
       request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       string reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

       username = Regex.Match(Regex.Match(reader, "<input id=\"user_screen_name\".*?value=\".*?\">").Value, "value=\".*?\"").Value.Replace("value=", "").Replace("\"", "");
   }
   ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Don't do that.  Use OAuth and the Twitter API.

Comment: My Question Is : I can not get the UserName ?

Comment: How can I use OAuth an the Twitter API to do that ?